# How can I customize the public_activity rails gem to use a different "table" or "model" for "activities"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm new to RoR and am trying to use the public_activity gem with an existing application that already has an `Activity` model and `activities` table.

Is it possible to somehow configure or trick public_activity to use a different table & model without modifying the entire source code of public_activity?

I was thinking that the PublicActivity::Activity would just point to a different model class?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is simple.

Let's assume you would like the gem to use the `events` table instead of it's default of using `activities`.

After following the `public_activity` install instructions and generating the migration, open up the migration file it generated and change the table name to `:events`

**Open File:** `db/migrate/xxxxxxxxx_create_activities.rb`
and modify it like so...

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  # Create table
  def self.up
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.belongs_to :trackable, :polymorphic => true
      t.belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
      t.string  :key
      t.text    :parameters
      t.belongs_to :recipient, :polymorphic => true

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :events, [:trackable_id, :trackable_type]
    add_index :events, [:owner_id, :owner_type]
    add_index :events, [:recipient_id, :recipient_type]
  end
  # Drop table
  def self.down
    drop_table :events
  end
end
```

Then run `rake db:migrate`.

Then, create a file `config/initializers/public_activity.rb`
and add the line:
`PublicActivity::ORM::ActiveRecord::Activity.table_name = 'events'`

And proceed with utilizing the `public_activity` gem as described in the documentation and all is well in the hood.

[A special thanks to the developers of public_activity for assistance with this solution in GitHub issues.](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity/issues/87)

Comment: I'm getting `uninitialized constant PublicActivity::ORM (NameError)` with public_activity 1.4.1.

Comment: I think the solution was to just add `PublicActivity.config.table_name = 'events'` instead... still working on the updated solution though.

Comment: You also need to change the name of your migration file to `db/migrate/xxxxxxxxx_create_events.rb`, otherwise you'll get a `NameError: uninitialized constant CreateActivities` error when migrating.